# jQuery, issue with .animate() and .fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, fadein

Inside a div `.frame` I have 3 others div: `.top`, `.middle` and `.bottom`.

`.top` and `.bottom` are in `display none`, and when the mouse is over `.frame`, with the jquery function `animate`, the height of `.frame` is increasing and `.top` and `.bottom` are showing with `.fadeIn()`.

When the mouse is out `.frame`, the size of `.frame` is decreasing and `.top` and `.bottom` are going away with `.fadeOut()`.

My CSS are:

```
.frame{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
}

.middle{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
}

.top{
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}

.bottom{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
}
```

my HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom</div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
var t,
    h;
    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
        var el = $(this),
            top = el.children('.top'),
            bottom = el.children('.bottom'),
            middle = el.children('.middle'),
            mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";

        if(t == null){
            t = el.offset().top;
            h = el.height();
        }

        if(mEnt == true){
            middle.stop().animate({'top':'20px'});
            el.stop().animate({
                'height':h+bottom.height()+20,
                'top':t-20
            }); 
            top.stop().fadeIn(300);
            bottom.stop().fadeIn(300);
        }else{
            middle.stop().animate({'top':'0px'});
            el.stop().animate({
                'height':200,
                'top':t
            });
            top.stop().fadeOut(300);
            bottom.stop().fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
```

you can see the effect in the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/WE25E/

My issue (you can't see it in the jsFiddle but in my computer it does it) is when i'm entering and leaving `.frame` really fast and that my mouse is finaly over `.frame` then `.top` and `.bottom` doesn't want to `fadeIn` and all I can see is a blank

Comment: Have you got a link to your site as there is no issue with the code or fiddle that you have provided. I would assume a conflict is taking place somewhere.

Comment: no i'm working in local :( @Vector